# How to verify if a specific subset of the simplex is simply connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness, simplex

Let $ E = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x_i > 0 \text{ for all } i, \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i = 1\}$ be the simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If we now define the set

$$E_1 := \{x \in E: x_1 > x_i \text{ for all }i \in \{2,\dots,n\}\}$$

then I am wondering how to check if the set $E\setminus E_1$ is simply connected. I tried picturing things in 3d and I think it is simply connected in that case, but am having trouble finding ways to formally show this for general n. Any hints or direction towards resources would be much appreciated!

Comment: First, the simplex is usually defined with $x_i \geq 0$, not $x_i > 0$. Second, is your set $E \setminus E_1$ star-convex, or even convex?

Comment: Yes, you are right about typically allowing $x_i = 0$ however I am interested in the set E as defined -- sorry about the terminology issue. It is not convex, since I can take $x = (0.45,0.55-\epsilon,\epsilon/(n-2)...), y = (0.45, \epsilon/(n-2), 0.55-\epsilon, \epsilon/(n-2),...)$ which are both in $E \setminus E_1$ but x/2 + y/2 is not. I was not familiar with star convexity, will look into that, thanks!

Comment: You can find discussions of star convexity in most books on topology which cover at least a little bit of algebraic topology, for example Munkres "Topology". I find the theorem "star convexity $\implies$ simple connectivity" to be one of the first really useful theorems of algebraic topology.